# Multi Cores Architecture VS Multi Threading

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, multicore

Can we take full benefits of Multi core architecture without Multi threading.?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we take full benefits of Multi core architecture without Multi threading.?

For conventional environments; you can take some of the benefits of multi-CPU without multi-threading (e.g. if you've got 8 CPUs and you're running 8 separate single-threaded processes, then...).

For non-conventional environments, who knows? For an example, maybe the entire system uses the actor model (software divided into separate/independent objects where each object is an event handler), where the OS has a queue of pending events, and each CPU does "get event from queue, execute the corresponding object's event handler for that event" in a loop. In this case you can say that there's no threads at all (just CPUs and events) and therefore there is no multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

Can we take **full** benefit of multicores without multithreading ? Definitely no. But we can still have some parallelism.

As already answered, we can have several independent processes running on different processors to improve global computer performances.

And it is still possible to do parallel processing by means of interprocess communication ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)) as pipes or shared memory. For instance, if doing

`taskset 0x01 sort | taskset 0x02 uniq`

you will run two processes, sort on core 0 and uniq on core 1, and these process will communicate by a pipe (implemented in the shared memory). Note that this just an example and that OSes do run new processes on different cores without the taskset directive.

With posix [shared memory IPC](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html), you can do parallel processes running on different cores and exchanging data in a dedicated memory zone.

And you can use [openMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org/) to run multiprocess parallel programs on a multicore. The shared memory will be used to implement MPI message passing.

But in either case, compared to multithreading, the programming burden will be higher and performances much lower.